# Does the distance to the root entity have performance implications?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I was curious as to whether the distance from an entity to the "root" entity in a entity group had an effect on database performance.

I was curious because I was considering the idea of using the parent attribute as a sort of "linked list" like data structure for entities, with the root entity being the tail of the list and the newer values cons'ed (lisp sense of the word) as singly linked children.

Sort of like Entity -> Entity -> ... -> Entity -> RootEntity, where -> is the parent relationship.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Andrei and Jeffrey and would like to add some thoughts that partly overlap theirs.

First, the growth of key size with list length means the design will scale badly.  Imagine a linked list containing "only" 1000 entities.  The "sequence of kind-identifier pairs" mentioned by Andrei would store 1000 kind-identifier pairs in the tail entity key, 999 pairs in the penultimate entity key and so on.  Metadata space usage would approximate O(identifier size squared).  There is probably an undocumented byte count ceiling somewhere around a megabyte for an  entity's metadata.  The maximum practical list length will depend on server performance, with symptoms of above linear CPU cost growth as lists become longer, and (possibly) random timeouts.  There is an unfortunate inelegance in what would otherwise be a nice idea.  It will probably work fine with say 20 entities but become sluggish with over 100.

Second, the fact that a parent link is immutable means that the only valid modifications possible on such a list are appending to the list, and truncating an entire tail at any point.  You probably knew that and Jeffrey also implied it.  Third, as it's a singly linked list, a parent cannot know its child(ren), and a hard to detect bug might attach multiple children to the same parent somewhere in the middle of the list, resulting in a tree.

Answer (score 1):

Be very careful about this:  An entity's parent is actually part of its key.  So, if you want to insert elements or move around a subtree, you will have to delete and re-add the entity.  If that entity has a child, that child's key will need to change, too.  So you will end up having to delete/re-add every entity that is a descendant... Not good!

See:  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities

> The association between an entity and its parent is permanent, and cannot be changed once the entity is created.

Note that Jeff Schnitzer (of Objectify fame) recently [discussed this on he Objectify mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/objectify-appengine/ulqrSaWi3CQ/4gyPAZ_TnNUJ), and he made some suggestions on how to implement a tree structure within a single common entity group.

Answer (score 1):

The impact on performance depends on how you plan to use this entity. Under some scenarios (i.e. retrieving all children of a parent or getting a parent key from the child's key) the performance may event improve.

On the other hand, you may see a problem with updates of entities as there will be many more "writes" on each update (it probably affects costs more than performance):

> However, if the entity has ancestors, it requires a write for each
>   possible combination of property values and ancestors, in addition to
>   those for the entity itself.

There is also a limit on how many entities within a single entity group can be updated per second.

Also note that the amount of stored data may increase substantially, as you will have long keys for most entities:

> The complete key identifying the entity consists of a sequence of
>   kind-identifier pairs specifying its ancestor path and terminating
>   with those of the entity itself.

And if you index even a few properties for these entities, the stored data will explode because of all the required indexes.